# How to print Mongoose object properties with console.log?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

These are the schema from [mongoose subdocuments](https://www.codefornerds.com/mongoose-subdocuments-and-referencing-another-document-by-id/) example.

```
let classTypeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  abilities: {
    type: Array,
    default: []
  },
  skills: {
    type: Array,
    default: []
  }
});

let heroSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true,
    minlength: 3,
    maxlength: 24
  },
  classType: [classTypeSchema],
  level: {
    type: Number,
    default: 1
  },
  currency: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0
  }
});
```

I tried this way

```
Hero = mongoose.model('Hero',heroSchema);
console.log(typeof Hero);
console.log(JSON.stringify(Hero, null, 4));
```

Output

```
function
undefined
```

Console.dir gives very detailed output.I am interested only in schemas part

```
subpaths: {
  'classType.name': [SchemaString],
  'classType.abilities': [SchemaArray],
  'classType.skills': [SchemaArray],
  'classType._id': [ObjectId],
  'classType.abilities.$': [Mixed],
  'classType.skills.$': [Mixed]
},
```

Is there any other way to print Mongoose properties and methods?

Comment: You could try `console.log(Hero.prototype)`

Comment: To be clear, you want to see the methods and properties that Mongoose has in the model `Hero`, right?

Comment: Yes,exactly that.

Comment: Then you could try the above, let me know if it works

Comment: I t works althous some stuff like hooks: [Kareem] confuse me.